# Fragment instantiation: Why isn't savedInstanceState bundle enough?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've been using for a while the best practice recommended by Google of having a `MyFragment.newInstance()` static function. Though thinking about it, why can't we simplify it removing this static function, the call to onCreate to access the arguments, and only using one bundle to always save and retrieve the latest data when recreating the fragment ?
I made a simple test that seems to work just as fine as the slightly heavier current practice.
The state persisted after activity recreation, orientation change, and fragment re-creation in a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.
Am I missing anything?

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    private String fragmentText;

    public TestFragment() { } // Required empty public constructor

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment") 
    public TestFragment(String fragmentText) {
        // add here other init arguments 
        // don't save them in any bundle yet
        this.fragmentText = fragmentText;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // retrieve all arguments here 
            fragmentText = savedInstanceState.getString("fragmentText", fragmentText);
        }
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setText(fragmentText);
        return textView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        // save everything here once, only when needed
        outState.putString("fragmentText", fragmentText);
    }

    // Add your setters to interact with the fragment
    // those changes will persists after fragment re-creation
    public void setFragmentText(String fragmentText) {
        this.fragmentText = fragmentText;
    }
}
```

Comment: so what's the question ?

Comment: The one from the title. Why isn't savedInstanceState bundle enough?
Why do we need to add an additional bundle with setArguments?

Comment: You are not supposed to have a parameter in your constructor when using Fragments.

Comment: Because savedInstance doesn't call every time. It will be triggered when device screen will be rotated or when inner system kill application due to low memory and some more scenarios. So if you want to pass some values from activities to fragment or fragment to fragment you must have to pass it through Argument. There are plenty of others ways -> you can make static variable and store the value in it but thats not a perfect value to pass value -> it will consume lot of memory. So passing through argument is standard way.

Answer (score 1):

> Why isn't savedInstanceState bundle enough?

It is enough. The arguments `Bundle` is added to the saved instance state `Bundle` automatically.

> I made a simple test that seems to work just as fine as the slightly heavier current practice.

Your approach is roughly the same, in terms of lines of code, as is the factory-method approach.

> Why do we need to add an additional bundle with setArguments?

You do not "need" it. It is merely an available and recommended pattern for providing input to the fragment. You are welcome to do something else if you wish. Just remember to have the `public` zero-argument constructor as well as your custom constructor, since the framework will use the `public` zero-argument constructor when recreating your fragments.

Comment: The idea was mostly to centralize in one place the saving and retrieving of the data (data of init + data that were modified by the user after instantiation).
Not to mention that the argument bundle cannot be updated after the first instantiation. Here you don't worry about this, add your setters, interact with your fragment how you want, it will saved anyway.
Babu Patel mentioned `onSavedInstanceState` is not always called. I can't see in which situation? Is it true? Would you have an example where it's not called?

Comment: @GabrielMorin: "Not to mention that the argument bundle cannot be updated after the first instantiation" -- IMHO, that's a feature, not a bug. "Would you have an example where it's not called?" -- if your app crashes, `onSaveInstanceState()` will not be called. However, that does not matter, as the arguments `Bundle` is part of the saved instance state. In any scenario where `onSaveInstanceState()` is not called, you would lose the arguments `Bundle` as well.

Comment: Btw calling `getArguments().putString("existingString", "newValue")` wouldn't update the argument bundle? Meaning that you can update the arguments as well (even though as you said it's useless if it's saved anyway in the saved state bundle).   
If not being able to update some settings of your fragment after instantiation is a feature then it probably means I'm not using fragments according to their initial philosophy, i'll dig more into it.

Comment: @GabrielMorin: "Btw calling getArguments().putString("existingString", "newValue") wouldn't update the argument bundle?" -- it might. I have never tried that. I like keeping the arguments bundle intact, as a statement of the original settings of the fragment. "then it probably means I'm not using fragments according to their initial philosophy" -- not necessarily. Just because *I* like something does not make it a universal truth. :-) Having a recorded copy of starting conditions is useful in some places (undo, only modifying changed values, etc.), but it's not essential.

Answer (score 0):

Because **savedInstance** doesn't call every time. It will be triggered when device screen will be rotated or when inner **system kill application** due to low memory and some more scenarios. So if you want to pass some values from activities to fragment or fragment to fragment you must have to pass it through **Argument**. There are plenty of others ways -> you can make **static** variable and store the value in it but thats not a perfect value to pass value -> it will consume lot of **memory**. So passing through argument is standard way